# Xcode 4.3.2 gives error "cannot use super because it is a root class"

Tags: ios, xcode

Lately when I updated to xcode 4.3.2 I've run into numerous new problems. In my app view controller m file, I keep getting the error "cannot use super because it is a root clause."

I've looked on the internet for hours, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

Comment: Show us the offending code please.

Comment: Are you sure it says "clause" and not "class"?

Comment: Sorry it does say class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declared your class, you probably forgot the superclass in the `@interface` line.  For example, you did

```
@interface MyClass
{
    // ... ivars ...
}

// ... methods ...

@end
```

You want that first line to be:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
```

or whatever superclass you intended to use.

Comment: Yeah the clue is in the error message. Sometimes people need to try and solve problems themselves without going to the Stack Overflow community at any minor hiccup.

Comment: Well, that particular error message relies on the developer knowing what a "root class" is in Objective-C.  That's a somewhat obscure subject.

Comment: Having said that, I didn't but worked it out. 'root' normally has something to do with nothing being further up the chain, and 'class' means class. Plus I'm sure there are many Google results for this problem!

Answer (score 8):

This error may also come up if your class inherits from another custom class and if you used a forward declaration of your ancestor class (`@class MyAncestorClass`) in your header file, but forgot to `#import` your ancestor class in the implementation file.

Answer (score -1):

Use this solution will help incase you encountered this problem in phonegap

```
#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVCommandDelegateImpl.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVCommandQueue.h>

@interface MainViewController : CDVViewController
@end

@interface MainCommandDelegate : CDVCommandDelegateImpl
@end

@interface MainCommandQueue : CDVCommandQueue
@end
```