# RootViewController cannot use 'super' because it is a root class

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2, xcode3to4

While going through a tutorial which uses a navigation based- application, I decided to create a Navigation-Based Application with my 3.2.6-Xcode and open it with Xcode 4.2 for following the tutorial with that version. 
But when I open the same project in Xcode 4.2 (without changing or adding any code), the 4.2 Xcode gives me 2 errors saying:

> RootViewController cannot use 'super' because it is a root class

Right now, my Xcode has 4 class-files: RootViewController.h, RootViewController.m, SaveUpAppDelegate.h and SaveUpAppDelegate.m. The error is in `RootViewController.m`:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
```

and

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}
```

I already searched through the internet and found this discussion (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113669/xcode-4-3-2-gives-error-cannot-use-super-because-it-is-a-root-class) and they say that the reason might be that the controller is that the developer forgot the superclass in the `@interface` line. That doesn't fit to my case, because I (or better: Xcode 3.2.6) didn't forget the superclass in `RootViewController.h`...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
}

@end
```

right now, I commented those critical lines out and it works fine, but I'm sure, I'll need those lines since most of the automatic created lines in the m-file are done with [super ....].

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project?

Comment: sorry for that dumb question, but what do you mean with "cleaning" the project? Delete/Comment all the auto-created code out? - If you mean that: Yes. I commented the critical code out and it works fine now. But I'm not sure if I'll need that super-code during the tutorial. That's why I'm asking if there's another solution or if "super" can be replaced by something other.

Comment: did you use ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) ?

Comment: My project says that there's no Objective-C++ Automatic Reference Counting (it's set to "No") and I also couldn't set some checkbox like that while creating the project via Xcode 3.2.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean. It's an option under "Run". It removes all the build files that are automatically generated.

Comment: it works pretty fine now. Thanks. I realized that it's no problem to delete all those auto-incremented lines, because in the tutorial, they'll be set again, but with the appropriate lines.

Answer (score 4):

My resolution was more simple. There was a misspelling in the #import "ClassHere.h" in the .m file. This resolved the issue I had.

Comment: @Matthias, he means to say that the error that the OP is talking about can also occur when you have a typo in the `#import` statement or `@implementation` definition in the corresponding implementation file, in which case the accepted answer will have no effect. Thanks, for pointing this out, Treis.